# Compound functions: one to one and onto

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Let $f: A \to B$ and $g: B\to C$ be maps.

> If $g(f(x))$ is one-to-one and $f$ is onto, show that $g$ is one-to-one

I'm really not sure how to prove this. Would someone be able to walk me through the steps that one would use to prove this particular situation? I apologize in advance, normally I like to have some work to demonstrate my attempt, but unfortunately, I am just lost and don't even know where to start. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

$g(f(x))$ is one to one implies that if $g(f(a_1))=g(f(a_2))$, then $a_1=a_2$

$f:A\to B$ is onto implies that for every element $b\in B$, there is some element $a\in A$ for which $f(a)=b$.

Now you want to show that $g$ is one to one.

You can start off by saying "Suppose $g(b_1)=g(b_2)$", then try to show that $b_1=b_2$ using the two observations I listed above. Perhaps you can write $b_1$ and $b_2$ as $f(a_1),f(a_2)$ for some elements $a_1,a_2\in A$ (why is this possible?), then use the fact that $g(f(x)$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

You could try proof by contradiction.

Assume g is not one-to-one, then $\exists y_1 \neq y_2$ whereas $g(y_1)=g(y_2)$. Since f is onto, $\exists x_1,x_2$ s.t. $f(x_1)=y_1, f(x_2) = y_2$. Of course $x_1 \neq x_2$, but $g(f(x_1)) = g(f(x_2))$. So this contradicts with the condition that g(f(x)) is one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=g(y)$Now $f$ onto and note that $x,y \in B$ hence $ \exists a,b \in A : f(a)=x,f(b)=y$

So $g(f(a))=g(f(b))\Rightarrow gof(a)=gof(b)\Rightarrow a=b$(Since $gof$ one one and $a,b\in A$)

Then $a=b\Rightarrow f(a)=f(b)\Rightarrow x=y\Rightarrow g$ one one